# XML parsing with special character data in the nodes

Tags: xml, dom, xml-parsing

I was trying to retrieve data from XML using DOM parser. One of the nodes of xml has data with special characters like (single quote &squo and &rsquo may be some typo). So data retreival is not happening properly.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Can you post an example of the XML? And also the code you are using to parse it?

Comment: Does your document have a DTD which defines those nonstandard Entity References? If not, they can't be parsed. You could replace them with Numeric Character References, which will work without needing to be explicitly defined but will be less human-readable; if you go that route, make sure you use the numbers appropriate to the encoding of your document. (UTF8 or UTF16 are usually the default encodings for XML; if you're using something else you have to say so in the XML Declaration.)

Answer (score 0):

You can escape the data in a XML node with

```
 <![CDATA[yourData]]>.
```

The content inside this tag will be considered as a string so you can add special characters inside.